# CKEditor Error on Image Upload

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor

I receive the following message when I select an image to upload and then click "send it to the Server":

```
Unable to get property 'setCustomData' of undefined or null reference.
```

I searched for CKEditor setcustomdata but came up with nothing...

Comment: That's not enough information. CKEditor itself does not send files to server. You need both server integration and some plugin for CKEditor. You need to mention all this in your question so others are able to reproduce this problem or understand to what it is related.

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption that you are using the CKSource Image plugin. I received this error when I used the advice from this [post](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Dialog_Tab) about setting the default open tab to the Upload tab. I moved the this.selectPage('Upload'); into the onLoad event and no longer receive the error but it doesn't default the selected tab to upload on subsequent show events.

I hope this helps or at least gives you a direction to look.